What is wrong with this argument that we only need to consider Z stabilizers?
Pardon the basic question but I am unable to wrap my head around why this argument is wrong.
Consider a single qubit $\alpha\vert 0\rangle + \beta\vert 1\rangle$. I want to track its evolution under some quantum operations. Since $\vert 0\rangle$ is stabilized by $Z$ and $\vert 1\rangle$ is stabilized by $-Z$, I claim that as long as I know how the $Z$ stabilizer evolves, I can track the evolution of the qubit by independently tracking the evolution of $\vert 0\rangle$ and $\vert 1\rangle$.
But usually, we need to track the evolution of the $X$ and $Z$ stabilizers to make this claim.
Why exactly does one fail if one uses only $Z$ stabilizer evolution + linearity?
Maybe another way to ask it: If I know that $\vert 0\rangle \rightarrow \vert\psi\rangle$ and $\vert 1\rangle \rightarrow \vert\phi\rangle$ under some evolution, can I compute what happens to $\alpha\vert 0\rangle + \beta\vert 1\rangle$?

Consider two evolutions $$|0\rangle \xrightarrow[]{H} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle),,$$ and $$|0\rangle \xrightarrow[]{H\cdot S}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + i|1\rangle),.$$ What happens to $Z$ and $-Z$? How about $X$ and $Z$?

So the point is I need to track the global phase of $\vert 1\rangle$ for this to work in the above example?

Effectively, by tracking how the $Z$ stabilizer evolves, you aren't tracking how $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ evolve, but how $|0\rangle\langle 0|$ and $|1\rangle\langle 1|$ evolve (these being how $Z$ decomposes). The major difference is that these don't capture the information about superposition, particularly relative phases. For these, you also need to track a non-diagonal operator such as $X$.

I see. So another example compared to FDGod, does this mean that a Z stabilizer even fails to capture the effect of a Z gate since it attaches a phase to $\vert 1\rangle$ but not to $\vert 0\rangle$?

Yes, that's a particularly good example, because you can immediately see that if you have a $Z$ stabilizer and evolve it under $Z$, it turns into $ZZZ=Z$. Nothing changes. But you know that some states do change under the action of $Z$.
